# Why does OpenNLP training tool require so much time in a (non-)multithreaded setup?

Tags: multithreading, nlp, text-mining, opennlp

I have mined some training data from `Wikipedia/DBPedia` now (about 30MB of text).
I would like to train this model with opennlp but it takes like forever. My Mac has an i7 / 4 cores and it is running now for over 13h but still it is `computing the event counts`.
The problem could be, that it is not using `multithreading`.
Do you have any experience with that? How can i improve this process?

Comment: Can you provide some example code snippet how you conduct the training? Would be helpful to others to get an idea of your setting. Hint: 30 MB is not that much ;)

Comment: Totally true :) I used this here: http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training.tool

The text looks exactly like the example. So the text is really "clean".
After 24h i got an GC overhead now. Any ideas? :) Still thinking that this tool is not using multithreading - any way to do this?